# pass delegate from c# to c as function parameter

Tags: c#, visual-c++

I want to pass a delegate to C from C# as shown below.

> //C# code

```
Main()
{
    //something

    public delegate int watch(int BytesLeft, IntPtr response);

    watch test1 = fun1;

    SendImage(FileArray,Length,test1);

    int fun1(int BytesLeft, IntPtr response)
    {
        //unmarshall response
    }
}
```

C code is shown below

> //C code

```
SendImage(int data, int len, <function_ptr>test)
{
    //something
    unsigned char ptr[10];
    ptrByte = &ptr[0];
    //something
    for(i=0;i<num_of_packet,i++)
    {
        TLayer();//something:some call
        int check=0;
        check = test(bytes_left, ptrByte);
    }
    //something
}
```

How can I do this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mark the delegate with a [UnmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedfunctionpointerattribute.aspx) with the same calling convention as your other P/Invoke method signatures.

C# then handles the marshalling of the function pointer automatically, the P/Invoke signature of `SendImage` would look like this (assuming your delegate type is the same as in your example, `watch`):

```
[DllImport(...)]
public extern void SendImage(int data, int len, watch test);
```

Also, your delegate type declaration would look like this:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(...)]
public delegate int watch(int BytesLeft, byte response);
```

Comment: No need to use **Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate**?

Comment: Sorry, most of the time when I'm doing interop the function pointers are part of structs that get marshalled back and forth. Turns out you do actually need to make it an `IntPtr` and call `Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate`. I'll correct the answer for that.

Comment: Don't fix it, the pinvoke marshaller already does that.  Your code now doesn't compile, can't pass an IntPtr.

Comment: Reverted it, I wasn't at home and couldn't easily test my code.